# Add body class into phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

i need add class into body by phtml file **NOT xml**

i try

```
    <?php 
      if ($root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')) {
      $root->addBodyClass('whatever');
      }
    ?>
```

but not working

Comment: Why can you not edit the XML file?

Comment: you can create a helper and in Helper, you can create a method with your code, and in the layout, you can call your helper with arguments and add your class in body container.

Comment: Or, you can add your class with javascript from phtml

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš not use xml why page is category fishpig wordpress

Comment: @St3phan by js is slow